# How can a FlashLite Developer using Device Central emulate camera and file upload integration?

Tags: camera, symbian, nokia, flashlite, device-emulation

I am developing an application with Flash Lite designed to run on Nokia S60 5th edition phones using the Flash Lite API Bridge Interface. The application uses the API Bridge to access the phones camera and upload functionality to take a photo, display it to the user then upload it to a server. I am using Flash CS4 Professional and Device Central to develop and test the interface.

Are there any emulators that will run my flash lite app and simulate the camera? What are my options short of getting a phone and installing my app every time I want to test something new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[Remote Device Access](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Remote_Device_Access) also known as RDA allows developers to test their applications on a variety of Symbian based Nokia devices remotely over the Internet. The current setups consist of over 40 devices and various device models. Usage is free of charge for all Forum Nokia members."